# UIView GestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

The view creation :

```
var myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 40))
myView.addSubview(myLabel) // some label 
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.view.addSubview(myView)

var mySwipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "userDidSwipe:")
myView.userInteractionEnabled = true
myView.addGestureRecognizer(mySwipeGesture)
```

The called method :

```
func userDidSwipe(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right {
        switchToMain()
    }
}
```

This is not working, the method `userDidSwipe` is not called.
What's strange is that **the same gesture recognizer `mySwipeGesture` is added to another UIView** (that contains many subviews) and perfectly works !

Why isn't it working for `myView` ? What should I check ?

Comment: Please show the method userDidSwipe.

Comment: What is the type of the view it's being added to?

Answer (score 2):

Usually this works. There may be following problems,

1) Check userInteractionEnabled property of myView.

2) Check the frame of myView (maybe you are swiping on different frame).

3) There maybe another view on myView that is blocking the gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding another gesture instead of `mySwipeGesture` to `myView`

Replace your line

```
myView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
```

with

```
myView.addGestureRecognizer(mySwipeGesture)
```

Comment: I am adding the right gesture recognizer. Just a mistake copying my code in the question. I corrected it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**add this line in your code you did not tell the direction to swipe gesture**

```
 mySwipeGesture.direction = .right
```